# perlembed in pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, perl

Has anyone successfully used some recent perl_construct/perl_parse/perl_run routines in C pthreads under linux? (solaris? freebsd?)

I know that perl should be compiled with -Dusethreads -Duseithreads (i have read perlembed docs), but regardless of that it is, it's still giving all sorts of problems under different operating systems - mainly segfaults in various perl routines, as Perl_mg_magical(), when used in C threads... Are there some opensource programs that succesfully use such combination (perlembed+pthreads)?

WM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
The B::C perl-compiler with threaded perls creates such programs and has a test-suite, but no explicit threads stress tests. You can run the CORE stress tests with threads, which might work or fail under normal perl also.

When linux passes it usually does not help you in analysis, only when freebsd, win32 or solaris pass then you got some certainty of correctness.
It also helps if your libc is thread-save and perl uses them.

Beware not to use usemymalloc with threads.

Try google thread-sanitizer, which is slow but finds a lot of threads-related bugs, races, deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into the B::C, and thread-sanitizer, which i've just tried out, is surely a useful tool.